# Вопрос по async

Tags: c#, асинхронность

Здравствуйте. У меня вопрос по поводу появившихся в c# ключевых слов async и await. Я имею следующий код

```
class Program
{
    private const int Count = 100000000;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 0;

        //какая то длительная по времени операция которую нужно выполнить асинхронно
        //например загрузка данных с сервера
        AsyncOperation();

        // пока выполняется наша длительная асинхронная операция
        // выполним что-нибудь еще
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++) 
            x++;

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async void AsyncOperation()
    {
        const string url = "https://какой-то_url";

        Console.WriteLine("Async begin");

        var res = await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
}
```

В моем понимании это должно происходить так: при запуске асинхронного метода AsyncOperation() он потихоньку выполняется в каком-то фоновом потоке, а в это время в главном потоке выполняется цикл, выполнение которого происходит независимо от асинхронного метода. В общем цикл и метод независимы друг от друга (как я понимаю выполняются  в разных потоках).
Но на практике (в том числе под отладкой) я вижу совсем другое - долго выполняется AsyncOperation а уже после него стартует цикл. Так в чем же асинхронность?

Заранее спасибо

P.S. async и await у вас не подсвечиваются как ключевые слова(

Comment: Могу и ошибаться но у вас возвращает тип void что как раз и приводит к такой проблеме. попробуйте указать Task<TResult> :  
public async Task<TResult> AsyncOperation(){some code}

Comment: Я поменял в вашем примере значение `Count` на 1, и он сработал так:

1. Выводится `x`
2. Выводится `res`.

Для большого `Count` `res` успевает загрузиться быстрее.

Попробуйте вывести отладочную информацию _до_ начала цикла тоже.

Comment: к сожалению у меня это не так. Я поменял Count на 10 и все равно сначала происходит длительное ожидание выполнения асинхронного метода а только потом стартует цикл

Comment: @JuniorTwo: А если без отладчика?

Comment: без отладчика вывод такой: 

>Async begin 
....... // долгое ожидание около 10 секунд
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
[результат синхронного метода]

а я ожидал такое: 


>Async begin
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
....... // долгое ожидание около 10 секунд
[результат синхронного метода]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Нашёл](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4057926/276994)!

Проблема в функции `DownloadStringAsync`: она не возвращает управление сразу, и долго синхронно настраивает что-то, после чего лишь уходит на загрузку в другой поток.

В новом классе `HttpClient` такой проблемы нет, и он ведёт себя как и ожидается. [Пример](http://pastebin.com/Xy2EASKe):

для `WebClient`:

> [Main] starting async operation at 00:00:00.0002355, thread = 10
>   [AsyncOperation] started, at 00:00:00.0015422, thread = 10
>   [AsyncOperation] before await, at **00:00:02.3415520, thread = 10**
>   [Main] async operation started, starting loop at 00:00:02.3426597, thread = 10
>   [Main] loop finished at 00:00:02.3427711, thread = 10
>   [AsyncOperation] after await, at 00:00:02.6131047, **thread = 16**

для `HttpClient`:

> [Main] starting async operation at 00:00:00.0002270, thread = 9
>   [AsyncOperation] started, at 00:00:00.0016208, thread = 9
>   [AsyncOperation] before await, at **00:00:00.0545499, thread = 9**
>   [Main] async operation started, starting loop at 00:00:00.0565030, thread = 9
>   [Main] loop finished at 00:00:00.0565623, thread = 9
>   [AsyncOperation] after await, at 00:00:02.5950867, **thread = 15**

Таким образом, вы попали на баг во фреймворке.